# Visual Studio Copy Web Site does not work

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have been using VS 2010's Copy Web Site a lot to publish my sites to a Windows 2008 Server. I have now got a new PC (Win7) with VS 2012 installed, and moved my sites/projects to this new PC. But I can't get the Copy Web Site to work here. I always receive error:

`The ~/ directory does not exist`

There is no problem to connect to the same directory via Windows Explore FTP. I have tried to remove the cache from WebsiteCashe, but no help. Any ideas?